# Css list disappearing when mouse hovers over other objects

Tags: html, list, css, hover

I'm currently stuck on problem with my list, it disappears when mouse hovers over other objects like that (used dev console to highlight borders):https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOwld.gif

I could just increase margin-top but it would look unaesthetically.

My question is how can I make it not disappear when mouse hovers over other objects, I actually accomplished it on my other website but I checked code and I have no idea why on this one it works:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksfUd.gif Here is the navigation css code:

```
.nav
{ 
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
}
ol
{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 18px;
height: 35px;
line-height: 200%;
display: inline-block;
}
ol a
{
text-decoration: none;
color:#50394c;
display: block;
}
ol >li
{
float: left;
padding-left:45px;
padding-right:45px;
opacity: 0.8;
}
ol >li:hover
{
opacity: 1;
}
ol >li >ul
{
display: none;
list-style-type: none;
background-color:#ffffff;
}
ol >li:hover >ul
{
display:block;
padding-left:0px;
padding-top:14px;

}
ol > li > ul > li
{
border-top: 1px dashed #b97070;
text-align:center;
opacity: 0.8;
}
ol > li > ul > li:hover
{
opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is the headline and img css code:

```
.pillowheadline
{
width:700px;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
bottom: 40px;
}
.pillowimg1
{
width:500px;
height:300px;
display: inline-block;
margin-top:120px;
}
```

html:

```
<header>

        <h1 class="logo">PRZYKŁADOWY TEKST</h1>

        <nav id="topnav">

            <div class="nav">
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="#">Front page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recommended Products</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Pillows</a></li>
                            <li><a     href="#">Honey</a></li>                  
                            <li><a href="#">przykład3</a></li>                  
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Natural Products</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Cereals</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Wicker</a></li>                 
                            <li><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>                 
                            <li><a href="#">Dairy</a></li>                  
                            <li><a href="#">Herbs</a></li>                  
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>
```

Comment: I think it's a problem with `z-index`.

Comment: pls provide codepen or jsfiddle for this

Comment: @amitwadhwani No, we don't want that when we, Stackoverflow, have our own Stack snippet tool

Comment: @LGSon i m sorry i dindt get what ur trying to say? i am new to stach   pls explain in detail about this tool

Comment: @amitwadhwani  Read this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @YoungKyunJin I added z-index:-1; to .pillowimg1, .pillowheadline and z-index:1; to ol > li > ul > li and it's working now, please post answer so I can verify it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.pillowimg1{
  z-index: -1;
}
.pillowheadline{
  z-index: 1;
}

ol > li > ul > li{
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I think it is a problem with `z-index`

Comment: also z-index only works on positioned elements so I needed to add position:relative; to .pillowimg1 and .pillowheadline but it's a standart so I don't know if you should include that in your answer, anyway thanks.

Comment: @BernardCzostek It's my pleasure.